# function with return type uint8_t returns 4 bytes

Tags: c

EDIT: the solution to the problem was a missing prototype.

When i call `uint8_t foo(uint16_t bar)` and assign its return value to a `uint32_t temp` not only the LSB of `temp` is overwritten but more. How is this even possible? Compiler is GCC.

The calling code:

```
uint32_t temp = 0xAAAAAAAA;
printf("[%x]\n", temp);
temp = foo(me->bar);
printf("[%x]\n", temp);
```

the output:

```
[aaaaaaaa]
[4081ff]
```

Here the relevant parts of the implementation of foo.

```
typedef struct CMOCK_foo_CALL_INSTANCE_tag
{
  UNITY_LINE_TYPE LineNumber;
  uint8_t ReturnVal;
  int CallOrder;
  uint16_t Expected_nGoNo;
} CMOCK_foo_CALL_INSTANCE;

uint8_t foo(uint16_t bar)
{
  CMOCK_foo_CALL_INSTANCE* cmock_call_instance =
    (CMOCK_foo_CALL_INSTANCE*)CMock_Guts_GetAddressFor(Mock.foo_CallInstance);
  (...)
  return cmock_call_instance->ReturnVal;
}
```

Comment: Assignment doesn't behave like bitwise or. If you want it to you can use `|=` instead of `=`.

Comment: @Paul: he's not surprised about the aaaa being overwritten, but he expects just to get 'ff' back since the function returns uint8_t

Comment: what I would expect is temp to be 0x000000FF or at least 0xAAAAAAFF after foo returned 0xFF

Comment: 'ff' is the obviously expected (you assign a value of 255 to a number that could hold a bigger size).   The somewhat surprising thing is that you get the the 4081 part from the function back too.  See my answer below though.

Comment: @Nicholaz exactly, where is that 0x4081 coming from?

Comment: @Dill I'd expect `temp` to be `0xff` (i.e. `0x000000ff`) after the call. What platform are you testing this on? Is it some kind of embedded system?

Comment: I'd say it is from ReturnVal being passed down in full length.

Comment: That doesn't seem logical *at all*. Compiler bug?

Comment: System is Windows 7 64bit, Compiler is GCC 4.6.2

Comment: @Dill interesting... can you show us the generated assembly code please? This smells like a compiler bug to me provided the code you've shown us and your description of the problem is accurate.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you disable optimizations when compiling (`-O0`)?

Comment: Tried here on MacOS/gcc and get the expected result.  Edited my answer below.  Sorry for answering prematurely (and wrong).

Comment: Does the definition of `foo()` (or at least a prototype for it) appear before or after the call site? If it's after, the compiler is probably assuming `int foo()`, instead of `uint8_t foo()`, and generating code accordingly. Using `gcc -W -Wall` would warn you about implicit function signature assumptions.

Comment: @Nik + Boann I'll try to do that, but right now the build is done by a generated rake file and I'm not aware how to add some compiler arguments, will take a while.

Comment: @twalberg thats it, I had an empty header included. I'm a little puzzled as to why I don't get any warnings...?

Comment: @twalberg - Make an answer, so that I can upvote it and OP can accept it.

Comment: @Dill: What warnings have you enabled?

Comment: If you're using gcc, make sure you add `-Wstrict-prototypes` to the compiler options (maybe even make it an error with `-Werror=strict-prototypes`). But only do it for C compiles because g++ will complain if it's used for C++ compiles since it's redundant. I'd prefer if g++ would just ignore the option instead of complain about it so there would be one less detail I have to remember and/or fix when I'm mucking around with build scripts.

Comment: The problem is the ceedling-TDD framework I'm using, it's build process seems keeps some warnings hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the file that calls `temp = foo(me -> bar);` includes either the prototype or the full definition of the `uint8_t foo(uint16_t bar);` function before it is called, either via an `#include` directive, or by adding the prototype/definition earlier in the file.

Without an already-seen signature for the function, the compiler will assume the signature to be `int foo();` and generate code accordingly.

Using `gcc -W -Wall` to compile should generate warnings when implicit function signature assumptions are made.